# Cargar respuesta de formulario automáticamente sin botón

Tags: javascript, botón, carga

por favor me ayudan a cargar resultado del formulario sin utilizar el botón de Suma Total, que cuando pulse las opciones plato, bebida y postre el resultado aparezca automáticamente, ya intente con window.onload pero no me resulta, el código lo copie de una pagina y no entiendo muy bien como carga la funcion con el boton, si alguien sabe como funciona el código le agradecería una pequeña orientación, de antemano muchas gracias.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>CAFETERIA</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #e1e637;
    }
    h1 {
      color: #ff090e;
    }
    legend {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>CAFETERIA</h1>
  <form>
    <legend>SELECCIONE EL PLATO PRINCIPAL</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="n1" name="principal" value="12" /> Caldo de pollo
    Q12.00 <br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n2" name="principal" value="20" /> pescado frito
    Q20.00<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n3" name="principal" value="25" /> revolcado
    Q25.00<br /><br />
    <legend>SELECCIONE SU BEBIDA</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="n4" name="bebida" value="7" /> CocaCola Q7.OO<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n5" name="bebida" value="4" /> Jamaica Q4.00<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n6" name="bebida" value="5" /> Sprite Q5.00<br /><br />
    <legend>SELECCIONE SU POSTRE</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="n7" name="postre" value="7" /> Pastel de fresa
    Q7.oo<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n8" name="postre" value="5" /> Helado de Chocolate
    Q5<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n9" name="postre" value="9" /> Coctel de frutas
    Q9.00<br /><br />
    <button>Suma Total</button>
    
  </form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
  <script>
   
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', obtenerTotal);
    function obtenerTotal(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(event.target);
      const principal = parseInt(formData.get('principal') || '0', 10);
      const bebida = parseInt(formData.get('bebida') || '0', 10);
      const postre = parseInt(formData.get('postre') || '0', 10);
      const result = principal + bebida + postre;
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = result;
    }
  </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para actualizar ante un cambio, agrega a la forma un evento de `change` usando `form.addEventListener`.

Hice algunos cambios en tu función `obtenerTotal` para que fuera compatible tanto con `submit` como con `change`.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('change', obtenerTotal);
form.addEventListener('submit', obtenerTotal);

function obtenerTotal(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Selecciona los inputs marcados
  const principalRadio = document.querySelector('input[name=principal]:checked')
  const bebidaRadio = document.querySelector('input[name=bebida]:checked')
  const postreRadio = document.querySelector('input[name=postre]:checked')
  
   // Obtiene el valor de los inputs
  const principal = principalRadio ?  Number(principalRadio.value): 0
  const bebida = bebidaRadio ? Number(bebidaRadio.value): 0 
  const postre = postreRadio ? Number(postreRadio.value): 0
  const result = principal + bebida + postre;
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = result
}
```

```css
body {
      background-color: #e1e637;
    }
h1 {
  color: #ff090e;
}
legend {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>CAFETERIA</h1>
  <form>
    <legend>SELECCIONE EL PLATO PRINCIPAL</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="n1" name="principal" value="12" /> Caldo de pollo
    Q12.00 <br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n2" name="principal" value="20" /> pescado frito
    Q20.00<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n3" name="principal" value="25" /> revolcado
    Q25.00<br /><br />
    <legend>SELECCIONE SU BEBIDA</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="n4" name="bebida" value="7" /> CocaCola Q7.OO<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n5" name="bebida" value="4" /> Jamaica Q4.00<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n6" name="bebida" value="5" /> Sprite Q5.00<br /><br />
    <legend>SELECCIONE SU POSTRE</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="n7" name="postre" value="7" /> Pastel de fresa
    Q7.oo<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n8" name="postre" value="5" /> Helado de Chocolate
    Q5<br /><br />
    <input type="radio" id="n9" name="postre" value="9" /> Coctel de frutas
    Q9.00<br /><br />
    <button>Suma Total</button>
</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime sos un crack, realmente estaba estancado y era lo que necesitaba y el codigo es mas facil de entender :-)